# Creating Multiple instances of a "Robot"

Tags: java

I'm learning programming at University (We are using the Learning to program with Robots Book/Package -becker.robots) and we have been assigned a project in which we have to create a Robot that escapes the room. I have that part done correctly and working.

We then have to create 10 Robots that spawn randomly and find their way out of the room. I honestly have no idea how to go about creating multiple Robots(my previous code will work for a a Robot that spawns anywhere so no problem with that).

My professor mentioned that the code should be contained in the main for this part and we should be using a Math.Random in some way. That was it...

We also have to add a counter to count the average number of moves made by these Robots.

I'm not looking for answers or anything, just a hand in the right direction as I'm very very stuck. Sorry if this isn't clear by the way. I find it pretty difficult to explain it.

Comment: OK.. please explain your problem.Is your problem that you are unable to find that how can you activate 10 robots at a time , mean you need 10 active robots every time to assign task to them? right?

Comment: I would remove your answers from github (and here). Otherwise people might copy off of you and you'll get blamed for cheating.

Comment: Yea Freak that is correct. I realise I have to use a for loop of some kind but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the robots don't have to move simultaneously. So you could just spawn a robot, let him find the exit, and go on to the next robot. Put the last to lines of `main` in a loop, and you're done.

Comment: are you asking how to spawn a robot?

Comment: @Heuster Yes, but the robot has to spawn randomly in the "city" and they have to move one after each other.

Comment: @Strobe_ Have you heard about Collections/Generics in Java? They are datastructures to hold object in memory. have you?n place all these robots in a list and iterate over them one by one using for/foreach loop

Comment: @freak Nope we have not studied them, it was implied there is an easier way to do it by just using a loop.

Comment: then try them.or use simple loop to get one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java when you need to create a new object of something you use the `new` keyword

the code will look something like this

```
Robot r = new Robot(<paramaters>);
```

java also has a function called `math.random()` that will return a double value between 0.0 and 1.0. you can get this to give you a value from 0 to n by multiplying the value returned by math.random() with n. i.e.

```
//Returns value from 0 - n
n*math.random
```

you can use this to give random locations at which to initialize the robots.

By doing this in a loop, you can declare a new robot and have it escape the maze multiple times

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop to create several instances of Robots, and in the loop you randomize the initial conditions of each robot (location and direction?)

Moreover, If you want to run the robots concurrently then you would have to use multi threads (which I think if out of scope for this type of exercise)

Comment: Thanks man. Wish I could green tick you as well.